# Drawing Transparent lines on Bitmap Android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas, android-bitmap

so I am running into an issue when I'm trying to create transparent lines in my android drawing app. My desired functionality is for these transparent lines' alpha channels to remain consistent as I continue to draw. What is happening is that the transparent line is being created, but as I continue to draw with the same line, the opacity of the older parts of the line begins to increase. I added a sample of this and also the code snippets that correlate with this. I have tried playing around with the PorterDuffXfermode however it seems to yield the same result or the transparent line overwrites the lines it draws over. Any ideas, hints or links would totally be grateful. Cheers!

**Code**
[image]
[image]
[image]
**Drawing**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are drawing over the faded line over and over in `touchedMove()`. As a result you line gets darker where there has been more overdraw and lighter where there has been less.

I would do all drawing in `onDraw()` or `draw()`. You invalidate the view, so continue to do that and draw only once. If you want to continue with what you have, only draw the portion of the line that the motion event represents.